# Hamlet - what does "O heart, lose not thy nature" (Act 3, scene 2) mean?

Tags: shakespeare

In Hamlet's soliloquy at the end of Act 3, scene 2 What does the line, "O heart, lose not thy nature" mean?

SparkNotes's No Fear Shakespeare interprets it to "Oh, heart, don’t grow weak."

shakespeare-online.com interprets it to "lose not the natural feelings between a son and his mother"

Comment: The interpretation *"Oh heart, don't grow weak"* seems to be contradicted by the following lines *"let not ever the soul of Nero enter this firm bosom: Let me be cruel, not unnatural."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand it to mean both of those things. Shakespeare managed to pack a lot of meaning into his words. He would have been aware of all the possible senses.

If you wish to answer the question for yourself, think about what the **nature of heart** is in metaphor.

If we set aside science and medicine, the word 'heart' is most often used in relation to love and to courage.

The following website archives many sayings about the heart.

[Heart Quotes and Proverbs](http://heartquotes.com/Heart-quotes.html)

http://heartquotes.com/Heart-quotes.html

ADDENDUM

The word 'courage' derives ultimately from the Latin 'cor' meaning 'heart'.

> **[courage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=courage&searchmode=none)** (n.) Look up courage at Dictionary.comc. 1300, from Old French
>   corage (12c., Modern French courage) "heart, innermost feelings;
>   temper," from Vulgar Latin *coraticum (source of Italian coraggio,
>   Spanish coraje), **from Latin cor "heart,"** from PIE root *kerd- (1)
>   "heart" (see heart (n.)) which remains a common metaphor for inner
>   strength. In Middle English, used broadly for "what is in one's mind
>   or thoughts," hence "bravery," but also "wrath, pride, confidence,
>   lustiness," or any sort of inclination. Replaced Old English ellen,
>   which also meant "zeal, strength."